# Is there a order of operations when I use substitution?

Tags: induction, exponentiation, substitution

I was doing a proof by induction and stepped over something, which I intuitively thought it has to be wrong. But I better ask:

proof by induction that this is divisible by 15:

$$ 2^{4n}-1 $$

i)Basis n=1

ii) assume n=k works

iii) try out n=k+1

$$ i) 2^4-1:15=1 \\ii) 2^{4k}-1=15q \\iii) 2^{4(k+1)}-1=2^{4}*2^{4k}-1$$

And this is where I was confused and I thought that this must be illegal: 
**May I substitute $$15q=2^{4k}-1$$ here?**

In my opinion this is forbidden since the order of operation would be violated.

I rather did the following:

$$15q=2^{4k}-1  \space |+1 \\15q+1=2^{4k} \\=> iii) 2^4(15q+1)-1\\=16*15q-15\\=(16q-1)*15=>divisible \space by \space 15$$

Comment: It should be $2^{4*k}-1=15*q$ at step $(ii)$. Further it is mathematically alright to substitute the assumed form in the further steps, here $2^{4*k}=15*q+1$.

Comment: Yes I messed it up when typing.

Comment: You're right, you can't $15q=2^{4k}-1$ but what you did instead looks good.

Comment: If one number is equal to another you can substitute one for the other - if two expressions represent the same number there is no problem making the substitution.

Comment: Well I would do a low-level proof: 3*2-1 = 5 ; we know that 2-1=1; When we substitute 1 for (2-1) we would have 3*1 which is not 5. So I guess substituting then is illegal.

Comment: Note in your counter example you are interpreting $3*2-1$ as $3*(2-1)$. which is not the way conventionally operations on numbers are used.

Comment: Yeah, so it would also be illegal to substitute something for $$2^{4k}-1$$ in  $$(anything)*2^{4k}-1$$ since I would interpret this as $$ anything*(2^{4k}-1)$$ right?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody